# See all local branches in all repos in Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, branch, git-branch

I'd like a better way to see all local branches in Git repos in Eclipse, so I can remind myself to either finish working on them or, if already merged, delete them. I can right-click and select Switch To on each repo in Git Repositories view, but that's a rather tedious affair. I want to see the branches of all repos at once.

Or, even better, see all local branches that are not "main branches" according to some rule (e.g. all branches not titled "develop" or "master").

Comment: The _Branch_ command shows the _Branches_ dialog which provides all the functionality you mentioned. You can get it e.g. via Ctrl+3 and typing `branch`. Or assign a shortcut in the preferences _General > Keys_ for the _Branch_ command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can just go to the "Git Repositories" view, focus on the repository you want (it's not clear whether you are referring to all branches in a single repository, or all branches in all repositories), and expand that tree element, showing the "Branches" element.  Expand that, seeing the "Local" element, then expand that, which shows all the local branches for that repository.

Comment: I mean all repos.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that.